Angular Ngrx Signal store A type annotation is necessary Error
I am writing a signal store with Angular 18 and @ngrx/signals: ^17.2.0,
the code is returning me this error:
error TS2742: The inferred type of 'x' cannot be named without a reference to '../../../../../../../node_modules/@ngrx/signals/src/deep-signal'.
This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary.

The error only appears when using a use nested object; with a non-nested object - it works.
The code:
import { signalStore, withState } from '@ngrx/signals';
import { SidebarSettingsState} from '../types';

const initialState: SidebarSettingsState = {
  theme: 'sidebar-dark',
  collapsed: false,
  logo: {
    theme: 'bg-blue',
  },
};

export const SidebarSettingsStore = signalStore(
  withState<SidebarSettingsState>(initialState)
);

I have tried many things, ChatGPT, TabNine, and adding type any, but these all have problems where the template is not accessing the data.

Welcome to Stackoverflow. Try re-installing your node_modules and let me know if it works.

@jburtondev thanks for the answer, the error is the same. Can it be because of difference in versions, cause angular is 18 and nrgx/signal is ^17.2.0 , if the object is not nested its ok, but if is nested is giving the error

Have a read into how deep-signal is working. It is the problem - ngrx essentially slices a larger signal into queryable chunks of state. There is some setup to make this work properly, you're not far off from it working. If you run into anything - feel free to ping.

@jburtondev i did it all night and nothing i even copy the same example that they have here -> https://ngrx.io/guide/signals/signal-store but the error is the same, everywhere they are doing what i did in my example and its working, i dont know whats is going on, i even create a new fresh library just to test it, the result is the same

Can you please provide a Stackblitz link with your code running.

sorry i am new to this stackblitz, i created a project but not a library, and it worked, but i my computer does not. i gave up allready, i will not use signalstore, i will just go with the old ngrxStore, thanks for the help

I used the store in my main project and it worked, the issue is when using it in a library in my workspace.

I see that a new version of signals just released, try:
npm/yarn i @ngrx/signals@18.0.0-rc.1

Thank u it resolve the issue

Thank u, i think the problem was a mismatch in ngrx/signal library
